# Element is removed from QList but static counter of existing objects doesn't decrease

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qlist

I have question about removing element from QList.

"myclass.h":

```
class node2D : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    node2D(){++s_NCount;};
    ~node2D(){--s_NCount;};

    int checkCount(){return s_NCount;};

private:
    static int s_NCount;
};
```

"myclass.cpp":

```
int node2D::s_NCount = 0;
```

"main.cpp":

```
void main()
{
    int i,max_el(4);
    QList<node2D*> *Nlist;
    Nlist = new QList<node2D*>;

    node2D controlNode;

    for (i = 0 ;i < max_el ; i++)
    {
        Nlist->append(new node2D);
    }

    cout << "Nlist size before: " << Nlist->size() << endl;
    cout << "Number of nodes before removing: " << controlNode.checkCount() << endl;

    Nlist->clear();
    cout << "NList size after: " << Nlist->size() << endl;
    delete Nlist;
    cout << "Number of nodes after removing: " << controlNode.checkCount() << endl;
}
```

After executing I get:

- NList size before: 4
- Number of nodes before removing: 5
- NList size after: 0
- Number of nodes after removing: 5

What's bothering me is the fact that number of node2D objects is still 5 instead of 1.

Of course it can be managed like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < Nlist->size(); i++)
{
    delete (*Nlist)[i];
}
Nlist->clear();
```

but shouldn't node2D objects be automatically deleted while Nlist->clear()?

**Or does it only happen when there is parent-child relation?**

Thanks in advance,

Pawel

Comment: Your delete loop above can be replaced with a single call to `qDeleteAll(NList)`, which is both more convenient and readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but shouldn't node2D objects be automatically deleted while Nlist->clear()?

Not at all. What if i want to use these objects somewhere else, which is the case mostly for me. Managing the objects pointed by the pointers you add to the list is your concern, not QList's. Managing the copies of these pointers is on the other hand, QList's concern.

Comment: And how about parent(QList)-child(every node2D) relation? Would it happen automatically then?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "child relation"?

Comment: If you make node2D objects child of the NList, then they will be deleted when Nlist is deleted, but not when NList is cleared.

Comment: @Tyler: Moomin talks about the parent-child relationship of QObject instances in Qt, which is not present in the code snippet above.

Comment: parent-child: setting Nlist as a parent of any node2d created within this list. I think that it is one of QT features that deleting parent object should delete all its childs

Comment: QObjects do handle the deletion of their children, but QList isn't a QObject, so that isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with QT in particular, but normally generic containers do not delete contained pointers on destruction, since there are many cases in which that would not be what the programmer wants. It works this way in the C++ STL and I can't imagine it would work differently in QT.

If you had inserted `Node2D` *objects* instead of *pointers to* `Node2D` objects, then the container would have made a copy of the contained objects and would have destructed those copies when the list destructed. When you insert a pointer, it makes a copy of the *pointer*, not the object, and so it remains up to you (the inserter) to manually manage the lifetime of the pointed-to object.

Comment: That's right, but unfortunately I need to use pointers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the QList you only store the pointers to an object. So if you clear the list you remove the reference to this pointer (aka the memory address). If you want to clear the object it self you can use smart pointers. In fact, you should pretty much always use smart pointers.

Try this instead

```
void main()
{
    int i,max_el(4);
    QList<QSharedPointer<node2D> > Nlist;


    node2D controlNode; //if you mixt QSharedPointer and objects like this, maybe you are better off using QExplicitelySharedDataPointer or QSharedDataPointer

    for (i = 0 ;i < max_el ; i++)
    {
        Nlist.append(QSharedPointer<node2D>(new node2D));
    }

    cout << "Nlist size before: " << Nlist.size() << endl;
    cout << "Number of nodes before removing: " << controlNode.checkCount() << endl;

    Nlist->clear();
    cout << "NList size after: " << Nlist.size() << endl;
    //delete Nlist;  not needed anymore since the list is not a pointer
    cout << "Number of nodes after removing: " << controlNode.checkCount() << endl;
}
```